# How to redirect http to https?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code that redirects non-www to www with https and it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that I when i go to www.site.com it doesn't redirect to https. I tried also adding the following code beneath the code at the top but I end up at https://www.www.site.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Just remove the extra www.

Comment: From where? the bottom? Because if I do that I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?:www\.)?(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that throws it into an infinite loop too.

Comment: There is no reason for that behavior. Did you remove the previous code?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the previous code. I'm using opencart and wrote the code you wrote underneath RewriteEngine ON from the original htaccess from opencart.

Comment: Could you post the code in the .htaccess file? There might be a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work on my host, but works perfectly on another one.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```